# MPI run error "caused collective abort of all ranks"

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to write parallel progra with using MPI in C. However, when I run my program I get that message and my program is terminated. I do not know the reason of that error message

> > WARNING: Unable to read mpd.hosts or list of hosts isn't provided. MPI job will be run on the current machine only.
> >
> > Solution is starting
> >
> > rank 7 in job 1  server_name_60409   caused collective abort of all ranks
> >       exit status of rank 7: return code 0
> >
> > rank 6 in job 1  server_name_60409   caused collective abort of all ranks
> >       exit status of rank 6: return code 0
> >
> > rank 4 in job 1  server_name_60409   caused collective abort of all ranks
> >       exit status of rank 4: killed by signal 9
> >
> > rank 3 in job 1  server_name_60409   caused collective abort of all ranks
> >       exit status of rank 3: killed by signal 9
> >
> > rank 2 in job 1  server_name_60409   caused collective abort of all ranks
> >       exit status of rank 2: return code 0
> >
> > rank 0 in job 1  server_name_60409   caused collective abort of all ranks
> >       exit status of rank 0: return code 0

Comment: Assuming you're running Unix, signal 9 is SIGKILL. It is often triggered by invalid memory accesses (e.g. buggy code that tries to read/write/free memory that it doesn't own). However, without seeing your code, there's not much more we can tell you.

Comment: @suszterpatt, invalid memory access triggers `SIGSEGV` (signal 11), not `SIGKILL`.

Comment: You might be running out of memory or hitting a CPU time limit as all your processes run on the same node. If any rank dies abnormally (e.g. because of CPU or memory limits being hit), the MPI launcher would kill the remaining ranks by sending them a signal, usually `SIGKILL` (9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you missed `MPI_Finalize()` after using `MPI`, it will also generate following error:

> rank 3 in job 98  n01_44763   caused collective abort of all ranks
>   exit status of rank 3: return code 0

Answer (score 1):

My program was aborting with a similar communicate:

```
rank 3 in job 58409  vnode-01_39157   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 3: killed by signal 9 
rank 1 in job 58409  vnode-01_39157   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 1: killed by signal 11
```

Due to too much stack memory being allocated.
Switching to heap helped.