# Understanding an MPI error

Tags: c, mpi

I am fairly new to computer science (chemistry background) but am writing a code that uses MPI in C. Every time I compile my code I get various errors, for instance,

```
rank 0 in job 1  cems_54844   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 0: killed by signal 9
```

Having had various errors similar to this for the past week I really could use some help with implementing some way to find out more about the problem.

The following [page](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node85.html) is about error handling in MPI. Unfortunately I don't know enough about computer science to understand this discussion.

With this I was hoping that someone would be willing to give me a crash course on handling MPI errors and perhaps shed a little more light (for the layman) on the linked discussion?

I am not asking a question about "will you write a code for me", I am asking for conceptual advice on how to understand MPI errors.

Comment: This is about programming. Nothing to do with computer science.

Comment: Please provide information about the system you are using, especially which MPI implementation, application, batch system etc. and more error messages. That way we can provide specific help. Note: `signal 9` is [SIGKILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) and is probably just an effect of the underlying cause.

Comment: The specific problem is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14061927/620382

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Programmers can present error information in many forms.  Often they will define a list of errors as a number (or more often as an enumeration which assigns numbers to labels in some order).

The first thing you need to find out is what an "Error 9" represents.

A quick bit of googling will lead you to several pages that list the various enumerations of the error codes, but most just show you the text not the numbers.  You can Assume that enumerations start at zero and count up until you get to 9, but that may not be completely accurate.  Also different versions of the software could add additional error codes to the enumeration compared to the list you're looking at so you need to look at the codes for the specific software and version you are running.  But.... 
I found an error list for  [Microsoft's MPI errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473298(v=vs.85).aspx) that lists this:

MPI_ERR_OP                     = 9

Or Invalid Operation.  Your program attempted to do an undefined instruction.

Valid instructions are defined here [for Microsoft's version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473436(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Signal 9 most likely has nothing to do with an MPI error code. It is most likely simply `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Your analysis of the situation is totally wrong. The error message clearly says "**killed** by **signal 9**". This is not an MPI error code; this is an externally delivered or internally raised Unix `KILL` signal (forced process termination), most likely the former and most likely due to the process exceeding its resource limits.